Is there a known correlation between the Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis (SETH) and the existence of one-way functions?
It is known that (one-way functions exist $\implies$ $\textbf{P}\neq \textbf{NP}$) and as far as my knowledge goes, the converse is not known to be true. Are there any known results correlating $\textbf{SETH}$ to the existence of one-way functions?

I think this might be relevant: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-96884-1_26
